# Estructura de proyecto Angular

Tags: angular2-template, angular

Estoy analizando el cómo comenzar a realizar un proyecto con Angular.

En uno anterior, que tenemos actualmente en marcha, montado con AngularJS 1.5, con una estructura similar a la que estoy buscando, la cual es una pantalla de login, la cual, sí existe el usuario, te pasa a una web.

Esta, se estructuró con un template abstracto, que tiene 2 hijos uno para el login y otro para el template con menu, el cual se emplea en toda la estructura interna de la web.

Me surge la duda de que en Angular 4 no se debe estructurar así el proyecto. ¿Podéis echarme una mano en como plantear dicha estructura?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dado por hecho de que utilizas el *router* en tu proyecto Angular 2+, puedes optar por tener tu **componente de autenticación** y tus otros **componentes de intranet** enrutados y así desde un tercer componente, por ejemplo **app-component** tener ahí el `<router-outlet>` de angular que controle qué mostrar.

> AppComponent.html

```
<app-menu-intranet *ngIf="authenticated"></app-menu-intranet>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

> LoginComponent.html

```
<form (submit)="onSubmit()">
  <input type="email" [(ngModel)]="email">
  <input type="password" [(ngModel)]="password">
  <button>LOGIN</button>
</form>
```

> Dashboard.html

```
<main>
  <h1>Bienvenid@</h1>
</main>
```

Aquí lo importante es tener [Guards](https://angular.io/guide/router), que no son más que los interceptores o middlewares de las rutas de angular. Aquí es donde decides Si el dashboard puede verse solo si está autenticado el usuario.

```
const routes: Route = [
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
    { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, canActivate: [ AuthGuard ] },
    { path: '**', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'login' }
];
```

### Actualizo

Un ejemplo de un Guard

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private router: Router, private authService: AuthService) {}

  canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
    if (!this.authService.isAuthenticated()) {
      this.router.navigate(['/login']);
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

}
```

Comment: Gracias! Es justo lo que estaba buscando, ¿el link de donde has sacado este código lo tienes? Me gustaría saber como monta el AuthGuard. Por lo demás es justo lo que necesitaba, voy a seguir investigando con esta base.

Comment: Bueno, por la red habrá muchos ejemplos, pero ahora te dejo uno de como implementar el Guard.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por el aporte!

Comment: De nada, si te ha resuelta tu pregunta no olvides marcar la respuesta como correcta.